# How can I find the value of y given x using matlab / octave

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, matlab, octave

I have two points on a plot
*point1=(40,5)* and *point2=(50,1)*

How can I find the value of *y* given *x=42.5*
I know y is 4 by looking at the plot but is there away to calculate the y value directly.

I found the slope:
y2-y1/x2-x1
(1-5)/(50-40) =-0.4

Example: matlab code:

```
clf reset
pts=[40,5;50,1] %x-y points
slope=(pts(2,2)-pts(1,2))/(pts(2,1)-pts(1,1)); %slope
plot(pts(:,1),pts(:,2),'-b') %plot line
hold on
plot(pts(:,1),pts(:,2),'r*') %plot points with stars
```

[image]

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, let's first find the equation of the line

Notice, the equation of the line passing through the points: $(40, 5)$ & $(50, 1)$ is given as $$y-5=\frac{5-1}{40-50}(x-40)$$ $$y-5=\frac{-2}{5}(x-40)$$ Now, setting $x=42.5$, we get y-coordinate $$y-5=\frac{-2}{5}(42.5-40)$$ $$y=-\frac{2}{5}(2.5)+5$$$$=5-1=4$$ $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{y=4}}$$